# Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Thread'

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

The following code demonstrate two ways of creating a thread that does the same job, but only one works while the other doesn't. The difference, from what I see, is declaration of a variable - could someone help explain why this leads to `Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Thread'`?

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Runs OK
    new Thread(() => { MessageBox.Show("foo");}).Start();

    // Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Threading.Thread'
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>  { MessageBox.Show("foo”); }).Start();
}
```

Comment: Start returns void and you are trying to assign it to a Thread

Comment: Pay attention to compiler messages. They are useful. A message that says it can't convert one type to another is telling that in an assignment of some sort, an expression having one type cannot be converted to the type required by the target of the assignment. In your case, you are trying to assign the return value of a method to a variable, when that method _doesn't even return a value_. See marked duplicates for just a handful of the Q&A you would have found had you searched the site for that error message, and which have plenty of information for you to understand the error message yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Start()` returns `void`. You're assigning the result of calling `.Start()` to `Thread t`, not assigning the thread itself.

You should do:

```
Thread t = new Thread(...);
t.Start();
```